# Create a mobile website from an existing DotNetNuke 5.1 website?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a Desktop website running on DNN 5.1, Now i want to create the mobile website for the same. Mobile website have its own new mockups and mobile website will be running on new domain like m.example.com.

I do not know how to proceed.

Any help appreciated?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this, but you likely would want to look at a module called MobiNuke, though I am not sure it works on newer versions of DNN, I do believe it works on the DNN5 releases.

If you don't care about keeping the content in Sync, you could backup/restore the site and simply apply a new skin to the site for mobile browsers.

If you can upgrade to a newer version of DNN, you could benefit from the content sharing features available in DNN7 to have two portals in your instance and share the content between them.